# String equation separation

Tags: java, string

```
String Str = new String("(300+23)*(43-21)/(84+7)");
          System.out.println("Return Value :" );

          String[] a=Str.split(Str);


String a="("
String b="300"
String c="+"
```

I want to convert this single string to an array giving output as above till the end of the equation using split method any suggestions
The above code doesn't works for it

Comment: Variables in Java are **always** in `camelCase`; `PascalCase` is reserved from `class` names (like `String`). No exceptions, no excuses. Please update your code.

Comment: If you are making separator between your val, you can split it with that separator for example a space like this String `str = " ( 300 + 23 ) * ( 43 - 21 ) / ( 84 + 7 ) "; String[] a=Str.split(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Str.split(Str);` , the parameter of the `split` function should be the string by which you want to break the bigger string into an array of smaller strings.
For example,

```
String s = "this is a string";
String [] array = s.split(" ");
```

The parameter for the split function here is basically just a space, so the split function will break the `s` string into parts delimited by the " " spring, which will result in `array` having the following values: `{"this", "is", "a", "string"}`.

I think this example is conclusive. What you are doing in your code is basically trying to break your string into parts using the string itself, which of course makes no sense.

You won't find an answer to what you want to achieve using just the split function, because there is no good string to act like a token by which to delimit the bigger string.

Comment: I wasn't done writing my answer, I pressed enter by mistake and it was posted, but I edited it in the meanwhile.  You are right about the new String("..") as being a mistake. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice as well.

Comment: Hint: you can always delete your answer then undelete it if you post by accident.

Comment: so can you suggest me how can I get my desired output  using which method?

Comment: There is no method that I know of that achieves what you want. But you can  create your own method that parses the string and splits it into parentheses, numbers and operators, checking character by character.

Comment: @CatalinFlorea Regarding the last part of your answer: It is possible with the split method using a regex instead of a token, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regular expression to achieve what you want, e.g.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String string = "(300+23)*(43-21)/(84+7)";
    final String[] arr = string.split("(?<![\\d.])|(?![\\d.])");
    for (final String s : arr)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Has to be modified a bit if whitespace could be present etc. but works for your example input string.